# Apex Chart line not displaying

Tags: vue.js, charts, apexcharts

I am working with Vue Apex Charts and noticed something strange. The chart is not displaying any lines only for one of the entries.

[image]

These are the options that I pass to the chart:

```
{
 "chart":{"width":"100%"},
 "dataLabels":{"enabled":false},
 "xaxis":{
          "type":"datetime",
          "categories":["2020-08-13T00:00:00Z","2020-08-14T00:00:00Z","2020-08-15T00:00:00Z","2020-08-16T00:00:00Z","2020-08-17T00:00:00Z","2020-08-18T00:00:00Z","2020-08-19T00:00:00Z"]
          },
"stroke":{"width":1},
"colors":["#567C9F","#C76C6C","#7B61B3","#A089D2","#633636","#443663","#7ACC80","#364E63","#9F5656","#2B4F2D","#7AA5CC","#569F5B"]
}
```

And the series data:

```
[{"name":"Adskeeper","data":[195,195,189,179,182,184,166]},{"name":"ContentAd","data":[1117,1120,1079,1080,1101,1168,1626]}]
```

The problem seems to be specific to the ContentAd one however the data supplied seems to be okay just like the data supplied to others. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I managed to fix this issue. If anyone has this issue in the future I think it's related to the very name 'ContentAd'. In `apexcharts version 2.4.1` if you put that name as a name of a series it doesn't display it all. Tried this in Code Sandbox with a clean project and got the same results with the versions of dependencies that I was using. It was a problem that persisted until `apexcharts 3.6.12`.